# Is there a bug in the "Layer 3D to Feature Class" tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, 3d-analyst

I am trying to convert an etruded polygon feature class to a 3D multipatch feature using the "Layer 3D to Feature Class" tool.  The result is a flat multipatch rather than the expected 3D feature.  I am exporting from ArcScene not ArcMap to ensure 3D layer properties are used. (ArcGIS 10.2.1)

Does anyone else have the same problem? Is this a bug? there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there's this bug: NIM099409 - Exporting extruded polygons to Multipatch with the 'Layer 3D to Feature Class' geoprocessing tool does not preserve extrusion if background geoprocessing is enabled. Found in 10.21, solved in 10.2.2. You can either uncheck background geoprocessing or upgrade to 10.2.2...

Comment: Thanks! I actually submitted a bug report but it must have already been a known bug then.